# Chennai Airport Luggage Storage

Tags: airports, chennai

Please let me know is there any cloak rooms available in chennai international and domestic terminals for leaving luggage?

Answer (score 1):

According to [SleepingInAirports](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/asia/chennai.htm#servicesFacilities):

> Luggage Storage & Lockers - Left luggage storage is available at a rate of Rs.5/- to Rs.20/- per item, depending on size. Location: International Arrivals, landside.